# strlen in array

Tags: c

I'm debugging a code in which a .ini file is being read for the value of string called Timeout(which is taken into a varibale called rbuf).Please tell me the content of the .ini file when the condition is as follows:

```
if((strlen(rbuf) > 0) && (rbuf[strlen(rbuf)-1] == '\n')){
    rbuf[strlen(rbuf)-1] = '\0';
   }
```

When will the debugger go into the above if loop?
Please specify the exact content of the rbuf value (Buffer value)

Comment: These 3 strlen's are hurting my eyes.

Comment: "If loop" is the classic first-year student slang.  Be savvy, call it an "if statement" as it is not a loop at all.

Comment: I tried with the following strings:

hello\n   ->this resulted in rbuf[strlen(rbuf)-1] value as n
hello\n\0 ->this resulted in rbuf[strlen(rbuf)-1] value as 0

Comment: @Satish - in c strings, the '\' character is an 'escape' character. The values '\n' and '\0' represent the newline character (ascii 13), which is a single byte, and the null character or null-terminator (ascii 0), also a single byte.

Comment: I still didn't understand the value of the string ! ;-(

Answer (score 4):

When the line has a 'string length' (anything greather than 0, not counting the null-terminator) and the final char before the zero-terminator is a newline, it will enter the conditional block and set that newline to be a null terminator.

In order to tell you the exact contents of rbuf, I would need to know the contents of the ini file. But, for example, if you had a line of text in it like:

`i love programming`

And lets assume there is an undisplayed newline at the end if it.

Then rbuf would start off containing:

`i love programming\n\0'

Thats 20 bytes. Strlen will return 19 (not including the null-terminator at the end).

rbuf[strlen(rbuf)-1] will be the '\n' character (at index 18 in the buffer).

So your code would see that a newline is at index 18, and set it to '\0', so you end up with:

`i love programming\0\0`

in your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say with the information you have given, but:

(strlen(rbuf) > 0) : rbuf contains a non-empty string
(rbuf[strlen(rbuf)-1] == '\n') : rbuf contain a string that ends with a line break.

Other than that, rbuf might only contain a line break. Or it might contian a series of charecters and ends with a line break.